# Nokogiri XML Builder Newlines Riddle

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, builder, libxml2

To build large and rather cumbersome AIXM (XML) files, I'm currently switching from the "builder" gem to Nokogiri's built-in XML builder. `DocumentFragment`s come in quite handy to build the blocks with which to assemble the final document.

Most `DocumentFragment`s have a container with which everything works like a charm:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('').tap do |document|
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(document) do |builder|
    builder.root do |root|
      root.foo('bar')
      root.fii('bir')
    end
  end
end.to_xml
```

```xml
<root>
  <foo>bar</foo>
  <fii>bir</fii>
</root>
```

Unfortunately, a few `DocumentFragment`s merely contain a bunch of elements. For some reason, the result is not formatted anymore, everything ends up on one line:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('').tap do |document|
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(document) do |builder|
    builder.foo('bar')
    builder.fii('bir')
  end
end.to_xml
```

```xml
<foo>bar</foo><fii>bir</fii>
```

Is there a way have newslines after each element as in the containered version?

(I've unsuccessfully looked for methods to extract part of a document into a new `DocumentFragment`, say, using the first example to build, then extract a `DocumentFragment` containing only the children of `root`.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer the question myself:

From what I read about other implementations using libxml2, this appears to be a "feature" of libxml2 rather than to happen on Nokogiri's end.

In any case, I'm working around this readability issue likes so now:

```rb
def build_fragment
  Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('').tap do |document|
    Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(document) do |builder|
      yield builder
    end
    document.elements.each { _1.add_next_sibling("\n") }   # add newline between tags on top level
  end
end
```

Then use it:

```rb
build_fragment do |builder|
  builder.foo('bar')
  builder.fii('bir')
end
```

To get:

```xml
<foo>bar</foo>
<fii>bir</fii>
```